# How to show Tanaka's formula is the Doob-Meyer decomposition?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis

In [Wikipidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka%27s_formula) it's said that the Tanaka's formula is the explicit Doob–Meyer decomposition of the submartingale $\vert B(t)\vert$.

In general we have that Tanaka's formula could be written as:

$$\vert B(t)-a\vert =\vert a\vert+ \int_0^t {\text{sgn}}(B(s)-a)dB(s)+\mathbb P\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_0^t1_{(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)}(B(s))ds$$

I can see that since $\vert{\text{sgn}}(B(s)-a)\vert \leq 1$ we have that $$\mathbb E\int_0^t \vert{\text{sgn}}(B(s)-a)\vert^2ds<\infty,$$

and hence $M_t=\int_0^t {\text{sgn}}(B(s)-a)dB(s)$ is a continuous martingale.

Then I should be able to show that $\mathbb P\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_0^t1_{(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)}(B(s))ds$ (the local time) is a predictable, rigt continuous increasing processes.

This may be straightforward but I am not able to see the latter. 
Could you please give me some hint?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not too difficult to show that the limit, call it $L(t)$, exists in the $L^2$ sense, and clearly $L(s)\le L(t)$ a.s. if $s<t$. Also, $L(t)$ is adapted to the Brownian filtration. And $t\mapsto L(t)$ has a continuous version because the stochastic integral has one.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I've followed you until the continuity part, to which stochastic integral do you refer? The integral in the local time is a Riemann integral

Comment: @RScrlli You need to read it the other way round: $$\mathbb{P}\lim_{\epsilon} \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \int_0^t 1_{(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)}(B(s)) \, ds = |B_t-a| - |a| - \int_0^t \text{sgn}(B_s-a) \, dB_s.$$ JohnDawkins was saying that the right-hand side has a continuous version and, hence, the left-hand side as well.

Comment: I get it! Thanks both for the help